# Duvida Laravel Trait

Tags: laravel, trait

Boas pessoal ,

Tenho a seguinte **Trait** no *Laravel*

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait Imageable {

    public function getUrlImageAttribute(): string {
        ....
    }

}
```

Uso a mesma no seguinte **Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Traits\Imageable;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;

class Page extends Model
{
    use Imageable,
        LogsActivity;

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'slug', 'image'];
    protected $appends = ['url_image'];
    protected static $logFillable = true;
    protected static $logName = 'Page Logs';
    
//RESTO DOS METODOS
}
```

A minha questão é porque que se eu colocar um `dd()` na **Trait** e fizer `save()` de algo no **Model** ele para no `dd()` e se procurar um id no `Model` com o `::findOrFail` já nao para?

Comment: Posta o source da trait e do model completo, aqui e se possível no paste.laravel.io

Comment: Ola está aqui https://paste.laravel.io/e1d53be6-9c0e-4d3e-8c6a-64314d89e187 https://paste.laravel.io/5cc3f346-f862-4a4c-97bb-4b0184fa8850

Comment: Provavelmente você está, após o Model::save,  redirecionando para uma rota que busca algo no banco, como está dando um dd no acessor getUrlImageAttribute() , o  dd não está parando no Model::save e sim após ele, ou seja, ao buscar os registros no banco